# Is there the equivalent for a `find` command in `hadoop`?

Tags: hadoop, terminal, hdfs, hadoop2

I know that from the terminal, one can do a `find` command to find files such as :

```
find . -type d -name "*something*" -maxdepth 4
```

But, when I am in the hadoop file system, I have not found a way to do this.

```
hadoop fs -find ....
```

throws an error.

How do people traverse files in hadoop?  I'm using `hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.1`.

Comment: It "throws an error"? What error? `find` is what I expect most people use.

Comment: for future help-seekers, on `hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.1`, it seems that this doesn't work:  `hadoop fs -ls -R <pattern>`, but a reasonable solution is this:  `hadoop fs -ls -R <filepath> | egrep <regex_pattern>`

Answer (score 13):

`hadoop fs -find` was introduced in Apache Hadoop 2.7.0. Most likely you're using an older version hence you don't have it yet.
see: [HADOOP-8989](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8989) for more information.

In the meantime you can use

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R <pattern>
```

e.g,:
hdfs dfs -ls -R /demo/order*.*

but that's not as powerful as 'find' of course and lacks some basics. From what I understand people have been writing scripts around it to get over this problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea how to use the `hadoop fs -find` "expression" option?  The docs say:  `The following operators are recognised:
    expression -a expression
    expression -and expression
    expression expression` but i have no idea what this means.`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the Cloudera stack, try the find tool:

```
org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool
```

Set the command to a bash variable:

```
COMMAND='hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool'
```

Usage as follows:

```
${COMMAND} -find . -name "something" -type d ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It you don't have the cloudera parcels available you can use awk.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /some_path | awk -F / '/^d/ && (NF <= 5) && /something/'
```

that's almost equivalent to the `find . -type d -name "*something*" -maxdepth 4` command.

Answer (score -1):

adding HdfsFindTool as alias in .bash_profile,will make it easy to use always.

--add below to profile
alias hdfsfind='hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool'
alias hdfs='hadoop fs'

--u can use as follows now :(here me using find tool to get HDFS source folder wise File name and record counts.)

$> cnt=1;for ff in `hdfsfind -find /dev/abc/*/2018/02/16/*.csv -type f`; do pp=`echo ${ff}|awk -F"/" '{print $7}'`;fn=`basename ${ff}`; fcnt=`hdfs -cat ${ff}|wc -l`; echo "${cnt}=${pp}=${fn}=${fcnt}"; cnt=`expr ${cnt} + 1`; done

--simple to get folder /file details:
$> hdfsfind -find /dev/abc/ -type f -name "*.csv"
$> hdfsfind -find /dev/abc/ -type d -name "*toys*"